# How to retrieve the user profile information using zend gdata

Tags: php

I have authenticated a youtube user using oauth( zend gdata library used).

```
$url = Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubTokenUri($returnUrl, $this->scope, $this->isSecure, $this->isSession);
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getHttpClient(Yii::app()->user->sessionToken);
```

How to retrieve the user profile information (I need his/her username)?
From zend gdata documentation I have found this code :

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$userProfile = $yt->getUserProfile('liz');
```

But, using oauth authentication, I couldn't retrieve the username.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, found the solution buried amongst [these responses](http://gdatatips.blogspot.com.au/2008/09/secure-authsub-using-zend-php-library.html)

```
$yt->getUserProfile("default")->username->text;
```

This will get you the username of the currently authenticated user